# importerror on pip install after pypi install

Tags: pip, setup.py, pypi

ref: https://github.com/louking/loutilities/tree/0.14.7

I am getting an importerror after pip install of this package. When I use easy_install of the egg all is well. Any help on how to debug would be appreciated.

Used following commands to install this package to pypi, and pip install using "pip 18.1 from c:\users\lking\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pip (python 2.7)"

```
python setup.py install
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
twine upload dist/loutilities-0.14.7.*
   :
# later
pip install loutilities
```

When I run the project, see the following

```
NoAppException: While importing "run", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lking\Documents\Lou's Software\projects\contracts\contracts\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 235, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\lking\Documents\Lou's Software\projects\contracts\contracts\run.py", line 31, in <module>
    app = create_app(Development(configpath), configpath)
  File "C:\Users\lking\Documents\Lou's Software\projects\contracts\contracts\contracts\__init__.py", line 82, in create_app
    from contracts.views.frontend import bp as frontend
  File "C:\Users\lking\Documents\Lou's Software\projects\contracts\contracts\contracts\views\frontend\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    import frontend
  File "C:\Users\lking\Documents\Lou's Software\projects\contracts\contracts\contracts\views\frontend\frontend.py", line 21, in <module>
    from loutilities.flask_helpers.blueprints import add_url_rules
ImportError: No module named flask_helpers.blueprints
```

find_packages seems to be finding the appropriate packages:

```
from setuptools import find_packages
find_packages()
Out[4]: ['loutilities', 'tests', 'loutilities.flask_helpers']
```

setup.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# [irrelevant comments deleted]

import glob
import pdb

# home grown
from loutilities import version

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

def globit(dir, filelist):
    outfiles = []
    for file in filelist:
        filepath = '{0}/{1}'.format(dir,file)
        gfilepath = glob.glob(filepath)
        for i in range(len(gfilepath)):
            f = gfilepath[i][len(dir)+1:]
            gfilepath[i] = '{0}/{1}'.format(dir,f)  # if on windows, need to replace backslash with frontslash
            outfiles += [gfilepath[i]]
    return (dir, outfiles)

setup(
    name = "loutilities",
    version = version.__version__,
    packages = find_packages(),
#    include_package_data = True,
    scripts = [
        'loutilities/agegrade.py',
        'loutilities/apikey.py',
        'loutilities/applytemplate.py',
        'loutilities/filtercsv.py',
        'loutilities/makerst.py',
    ],

    # Project uses reStructuredText, so ensure that the docutils get
    # installed or upgraded on the target machine
    install_requires = [
          'unicodecsv>=0.13.0',
        ],

    # If any package contains any of these file types, include them:
    data_files = ([
            globit('loutilities', ['*.conf','*.pyc','*.pyd','*.dll','*.h','*.xlsx']),
            globit('doc/source', ['*.txt', '*.rst', '*.html', '*.css', '*.js', '*.png', '*.py', ]),
            globit('doc/build/html', ['*.txt', '*.rst', '*.html', '*.css', '*.js', '*.png', ]),
            globit('doc/build/html/_sources', ['*.txt', '*.rst', '*.html', '*.css', '*.js', '*.png', ]),
            globit('doc/build/html/_static', ['*.txt', '*.rst', '*.html', '*.css', '*.js', '*.png', ]),
            globit('doc/build/html/_images', ['*.png', ]),
        ]),


    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': [
            'agegrade = loutilities.agegrade:main',
            'apikey = loutilities.apikey:main',
            'applytemplate = loutilities.applytemplate:main',
            'filtercsv = loutilities.filtercsv:main',
            'makerst = loutilities.makerst:main',
        ],
    },


    zip_safe = False,

    # metadata for upload to PyPI
    description = 'some hopefully useful utilities',
    long_description=open("README.md").read(),
    license = 'Apache License, Version 2.0',
    author = 'Lou King',
    author_email = 'lking@pobox.com',
    url = 'http://github.com/louking/loutilities',
    # could also include long_description, download_url, classifiers, etc.
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `pip install loutilities` I see an unknown directory `loutilities` at the top-level of my virtual environment. The directory contains a few `*.pyc` but not any subdirectory. I suspect `import loutilities.flask_helpers` tries to find a subdirectory `loutilities/flask_helpers` and fails.

I think the top-level directory is from the code

```
        globit('loutilities', ['*.conf','*.pyc','*.pyd','*.dll','*.h','*.xlsx']),
```

I suspect there is a bug in `globit()` that puts the data in the wrong directory.

Comment: Hmm, I'll look at that -- thanks for the hint. Is there any way to test updates without new upload (and new version number) to pypi? Sorry I'm such a noob with pypi.

Comment: For the life of me I don't understand why I am doing that globit code -- probably was needed in another repo and I just copied it. That's the problem when I originally built this 7 years ago... :) Anyway, still wondering the best way to test updates.

Comment: Never mind -- I think I just need to use TestPyPi to check it out. I'll verify the fix then assuming ok will accept your answer. Thanks again.